# How configure Zend\Di

Tags: zend-framework, dependency-injection, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

I need a help with Zend\Di;

I'm tired on the task of write factories to my application using the Zend\ServiceManager, I want to understand how work the configuration in MVC environment of Zend\Di.

I see [this post of @Ocramius](http://ocramius.github.io/blog/zend-framework-2-controllers-and-dependency-injection-with-zend-di/), with some configuration in the `module.config.php`, in the top key `di`:

```
<?php

return array(
    'di' => array(
        'allowed_controllers' => array(
            // this config is required, otherwise the MVC won't even attempt to ask Di for the controller!
            'Application\Controller\GreetingController',
        ),

        'instance' => array(
            'preference' => array(
                // these allow injecting correct EventManager and ServiceManager
                // (taken from the main ServiceManager) into the controller,
                // because Di doesn't know how to retrieve abstract types. These
                // dependencies are inherited from Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController
                'Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface' => 'EventManager',
                'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface' => 'ServiceManager',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    // remaining config
);
```

Anyone can post a url to the doc of this configuration or more detailed examples here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of different controllers and have a lot of services to choose from, then the ones with Configuration or Annotation should be the choices in this link: https://github.com/ralphschindler/Zend_DI-Examples

I think you should look at some libraries like [Aura.Di](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Di) or [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/). They provide even powerful DI containers.

If you have minimal services to inject, use initializers. Check this out: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/zendservicemanager-configuration-keys/

Comment: Is not the same thing and can't have much initializers, each are executed on every request to the service manager.

Comment: If you have a lot of different controllers and have a lot of services to choose from, then the ones with Configuration or Annotation should be the choices in this link:https://github.com/ralphschindler/Zend_DI-Examples

Comment: Thanks, I will try use this in the key "di"w of the module.config.php. Is sad that not have a well documented way to make this. Change your response or response again to I choose as the correct.

Comment: Check my latest answer. Yes, the examples dont have much documentation. It is just to give an idea of what is possible. You should take a look at Aura.Di or Pimple, if you have'nt already, they are pretty powerful too.